# Deselect a filter by another filter in the same table

Tags: filter, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

PowerBI issue: DOuble filter in the same table
I have 2 following tables,

Table 1

| Parent | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent 1 | Name 1 | Code 1 |
| Parent 2 | Name 2 | Code 2 |
| Parent 1 | Name 3 | Code 3 |
| Parent 3 | Name 4 | Code 4 |

Columns Code and Parent have multiple identical values
Parent has many duplicates

Table 2

| Name |
| --- |
| Name 1 |
| Name 2 |
| Name 3 |

I would like to search the value Name (Table 2) in table 1.
Then from the name found in table 1, take the code (Table 1) to search in the column  Parent (Table 1)
Ex : I search Name 1  in table 1
Name 1 has the code 1, I take the code 1 to search in column Parent, I have 2 results

| Parent | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent 1 | Name 1 | Code 1 |
| Parent 1 | Name 3 | Code 3 |

Note that I already has a filter of the name, then filter by the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table from your existing one and then apply some transformations as stated below. Fo example you have this below current table-

[image]

Now create a new table with only column "Name" from the above and here is the **Advanced Query** code for the new table (Don't forgot to change the table name in line 2 as per your table name).

```
let
    Source = your_table_name[Name],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Converted to Table", {"Column1"}, your_table_name, {"Name"}, "your_table_name", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded your_table_name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "your_table_name", {"Parent"}, {"your_table_name.Parent"}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded your_table_name", {"your_table_name.Parent"}, your_table_name, {"Parent"}, "your_table_name", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded your_table_name1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "your_table_name", {"Parent", "Name", "Code"}, {"your_table_name.Parent.1", "your_table_name.Name", "your_table_name.Code"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded your_table_name1",{{"your_table_name.Parent.1", "parent_new"}, {"your_table_name.Code", "code_new"}, {"your_table_name.Parent", "parent"}, {"Column1", "name"}, {"your_table_name.Name", "name_new"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Now you have a new table as below-
[image]

Finally, create your Name slicer from the new table and add the necessary columns in a table visual as shown below. You can also see the output when you select Name1.

[image]

Comment: Please don't forget the accept the answer and put an up vote if it works for you :)